# Controller not saving attribute (Oauth Token from FB)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

Weird problem - the create action in one of my controllers is not saving an attribute - check out the code below. All of the lines work until the last 2. The `oauth_token` and the `oauth_expires_at` are not being saved. I've checked that the attributes are named properly, etc. Funny thing is, if I change the second to last line to :

`omniauth['credentials']['token'] ? provider =  omniauth['credentials']['token'] : provider = ''`

It works perfectly fine. Something seems be wrong with the actual attributes `oauth_token` and the `oauth_expires_at`. I then tried to create 2 new dummy attributes to see if it would work there - doesn't. Seems like any attribute created after `oauth_token` is messed up. Is this a migration problem? Any ideas?

```
def create
    params[:authorization] ? authorization_route = params[:authorization] : authorization_route = 'no authorization (invalid callback)'

    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    if omniauth and params[:authorization]
        if authorization_route == "facebook"
              omniauth['extra']['raw_info']['email'] ? email =  omniauth['extra']['raw_info']['email'] : email = ''
              omniauth['extra']['raw_info']['name'] ? name =  omniauth['extra']['raw_info']['name'] : name = ''
              omniauth['extra']['raw_info']['id'] ?  uid =  omniauth['extra']['raw_info']['id'] : uid = ''
              omniauth['provider'] ? provider =  omniauth['provider'] : provider = ''
              omniauth['credentials']['token'] ? oauth_token =  omniauth['credentials']['token'] : oauth_token = ''
              omniauth['credentials']['expires_at'] ? oauth_expires_at =  Time.at(omniauth['credentials']['expires_at']) : oauth_expires_at = ''
end
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but I the way you are using the ternary (`condition ? value : other_value`) syntax is atypical. Usually, you would write something like

```
def create
  authorization_route = params[:authorization] ? params[:authorization] : 'no authorization (invalid callback)'

  omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  if omniauth and params[:authorization]
    if authorization_route == "facebook"
      email = omniauth['extra']['raw_info']['email'] ? omniauth['extra']['raw_info']['email'] : ''
      name = omniauth['extra']['raw_info']['name'] ? omniauth['extra']['raw_info']['name'] : ''
      uid = omniauth['extra']['raw_info']['id'] ? omniauth['extra']['raw_info']['id'] : ''
      provider = omniauth['provider'] ? omniauth['provider'] : ''
      oauth_token = omniauth['credentials']['token'] ? omniauth['credentials']['token'] : ''
      oauth_expires_at = omniauth['credentials']['expires_at'] ? Time.at(omniauth['credentials']['expires_at']) : ''
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

But, since you are using this to do `attribute = value ? value : default`, you can simplify it even more by using the or (`||`) operator for all but the last one:

```
def create
  authorization_route = params[:authorization] || 'no authorization (invalid callback)'

  omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  if omniauth and params[:authorization]
    if authorization_route == "facebook"
      email = omniauth['extra']['raw_info']['email'] || ''
      name = omniauth['extra']['raw_info']['name'] || ''
      uid = omniauth['extra']['raw_info']['id'] || ''
      provider = omniauth['provider'] || ''
      oauth_token = omniauth['credentials']['token'] || ''
      oauth_expires_at = omniauth['credentials']['expires_at'] ? Time.at(omniauth['credentials']['expires_at']) : ''
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

However, all three methods will work, so either `omniauth['credentials']['token']` isn't the right hash key, or whatever you are doing with `oauth_token` and `oauth_expires_at` later on in the controller or model is causing issues.

Can you edit your question to include more code from the controller and user model?

Answer (score 0):

I'm embarrassed to admit what the problem is actually:

Completely forgot what I was doing later in the controller. Gotta love careless mistakes...

Had to change:

```
user.authorizations.build(:provider => provider, :uid => uid, :name => name, :email => email, :user_id => user.id)
```

to:

```
user.authorizations.build(:provider => provider, :uid => uid, :name => name, :email => email, :user_id => user.id, :oauth_token => oauth_token, :oauth_expires_at => oauth_expires_at)
```